# Is Oracle unpublished BUG:8527473 fixed in recent versions?

Tags: oracle

I see that there are Oracle issues with ASLR on RHEL 6 on 11.x and 12.1.x.  Is this fixed in a newer version, and if so, which version?

Answer (score 1):

8527473 is not an unpublished bug.
It is fixed in version 11.2.0.2.

[Bug 8527473 - Various back ground processes fail to start causing instance to crash with ORA-443 / ORA-445 (Doc ID 8527473.8)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=8527473.8)